# How to fix react native video player visibility, when controls and sound are working?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

```
     *// video get from this* 
      const SampleVideo = require('../samplevideos/VID_20190811_172946.mp4');

     *// this is my app.js code*
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Video style={{ flex: 1 }} controls={true} source={SampleVideo}
                onPress={() => this.togglePaused(this.paused)}
                ref={(ref) => {
                    // this._player = ref
                }}
            ></Video>
        </View>
```

I am able to hear the sound of the video but the player itself is not visible, controls for the video is visible.

I tried many things to fix it but unable to find the solution.

Here is how it looks:

[image: Here]

Comment: put height and width in your video player.

Comment: I gave it still not working its some issue on emulator i think, If i gave height and width that space occupied but no visibility. On real device video displaying as expected.

Comment: be sure you don't have `hardwareAcceleration= false` in your` androidMenifest.xml `file.

Comment: No its not there

Comment: Thanks for the reply , In real device its working my question why it is not working in emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I think its emulator issue if I run the same code in the real device it's working fine